# ¿Cómo manejar un error en PHP?

Tags: php, html

Tengo un bloque de código que me sube archivos al servidor por medio de SCP SFTP.

PHP:

```
            $invoice = $_FILES['invoice']['name'];
            $path = $_FILES['invoice']['tmp_name'];
            $archive = 'gns-acs/images/'.$_FILES['invoice']['name'];

            $connection = ssh2_connect('IP', port);
            ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'user', 'password');
            $upload = ssh2_scp_send($connection, $path, $archive, 0644);

            if ($upload) {
                echo "<script>alert('El archivo se ha subido correctamente.');
                window.location.href = 'customers.php';
                </script>";
            } else {
                echo "<script>alert('Ocurrió un error al subir el archivo.');
                window.location.href = 'customers.php';
                </script>";
            }

            ssh2_disconnect($connection);
```

HTML:

```
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <label class="mt-3" for="voucher">COMPROBANTE:</label>
                <input type="file" name="voucher" id="voucher" class="form-control mb-2">
                <div class="text-center mt-4 mb-1">
                    <button type="submit" id="btnAddDeposit" name="btnAddDeposit" class="btn btn-success col-sm-4 col-5 mx-1"><i class="fas fa-save mr-2"></i> Guardar</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Cuando elijo un archivo me lo sube al servidor sin problema.
El problema es que cuando no elijo ningún archivo, me arroja un **Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: Path cannot be empty in**, en lugar de entrar al ELSE y mostrarme la alerta de error.

Espero y puedan ayudarme, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Y si mejor validas el contenido de `$_FILES` antes de llegar a crear toooooda la conexión y tal? Sólo digo

Comment: entre las buenas practicas del programador esta validar todas las variables antes de aplicar la lógica a las variables...

Comment: Ok voy a intentar validando esas variables. En caso de que en cualquier otro input tenga el atributo "required", ¿aún así es necesario validar en PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La validación de variables es parte esencial de la programación.

yo lo haría mas o menos así: evaluando si se recibió el archivo y se se subió al segundo servidor... y lo manejo con un solo controlador de errores.

```
try {
    if(isset($_FILES) && !empty($_FILES)){
        $invoice = $_FILES['invoice']['name'];
        $path = $_FILES['invoice']['tmp_name'];
        $archive = 'gns-acs/images/'.$_FILES['invoice']['name'];
        $connection = ssh2_connect('IP', port);
        ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'user', 'password');
        $upload = ssh2_scp_send($connection, $path, $archive, 0644);
        if ($upload) {
            echo "<script>alert('El archivo se ha subido correctamente.');
            window.location.href = 'customers.php';
            </script>";
        } else {
            // error por conexión/subida otro servidor
            throw new Exception('Ocurrió un error al subir el archivo.');
        }
        ssh2_disconnect($connection);
    }else{
        // error por subida del archivo a este servidor
        throw new Exception('No se ha Recibido el Archivo.');
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    //Manejador de errores genericos
    echo "<script>alert(".$e->getMessage().");
            window.location.href = 'customers.php';
        </script>";
}
```

Comment: Perfecto, funcionó amigo. A partir de ya empezaré a validar variables.

Comment: @tambien te recomiendo que implementes un controlador general de errores principalmente para desarrollo mira esto tal vez te interese: https://github.com/arcanisgk/BEH-Basic-Error-Handler y este otro: https://github.com/arcanisgk/BOH-Basic-Output-Handler

Comment: uno es un pluging de control de errores y el otro es para mostrarte el contenido de una variable.